# Content-Length diffrent in Safari and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, safari, xmlhttprequest

I am getting different value for ContentLength in XMLHTTPRequest from Safari, Internet Explorer for same UTF8 Encoding in ASP.Net is there anything affecting functionality in JavaScript which changes the format of string while using send(data) method

Comment: tell your code to console.log in both browsers and show us what the content is. Because it just might be that the content really *is* different.

Comment: ok, one difference I am getting is like this:
I am writing a value to string String.stringFromCharCode(834) + buffer, when I extract this value at server side in ASP.Net using BinaryRead() at that time it returns me 786 as Unicode char in Safari, Chrome while in Internet Explorer it gives me exact 834 Unicode value. this is the difference only. also string length is different in BinaryRead() at server side on internet explorer and safari. the difference in read string is of 2 bytes.